# How to JOIN MYSQL column and json

Tags: mysql, json

I need to join 3 mysql tables, 1. property 2. clients 3. category

in property table I have json colum and I need to join it in property table (content colum).

I'm write this:

```
$SQL = "SELECT p.*, c.*, ct.*
          FROM property p
          JOIN clients c
            ON p.user_id = c.id
          JOIN category ct ON ct.id IN JSON_EXTRACT(p.content, '$cat')
         WHERE public = '1'
         ORDER BY p.id DESC";
```

json in content column:

```
{
"image":["1.jpg","2.jpg","3.jpg","4.jpg","5.jpg","6.jpg"],
"image_title":[["title","title","title","title","title","title"]],
"category":[["5","41","41","42","7","41"]]
}
```

Can anyone help me?

error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON_EXTRACT(p.content, '6') WHERE public = '1' ORDER BY p.id DESC' at line 5

Thank you

Comment: AFAIK this is not yet supported in mysql.  It's available in postgresql

Comment: Thank you                    
@e4c5